# Python Webscraping: Why aren't I able to interact with the search bar on Linkedin using Selenium and ChromeDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I successfully automated logging in to linkedin, but I have not been able to successfully interact with the search bar. I keep getting "'list' object has no attribute 'click'". My code is copied below. I tried skipping the click method to see if I could pass information into the searchbar object, but that yielded the same error. The xpath is directly copied from chrome developer tools.

```
def linkedin_search():
    searchbar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember41"]/input')
    searchbar.click()
    searchbar.send_keys("Real Estate Investor")
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
linkedin_search()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need the `click()` method.  Try just sending keys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I just needed to use the find_element_by_xpath rather than find_element*s*_by_xpath. That one s changes how the object is treated. I should've done more research before posting this question...